# Appium paste popup

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, appium

In Appium I am doing longpress on the search field and trying to click on the Paste option that appears after the press, but I am not able to find out the element. Below is the screenshot of that :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8Suo.png)